# Get ListBox handle from Window handle

Tags: winapi, listbox, window

I am incredibly confused by the whole "window" verses "listbox" thing in the WIN32 API.  I am simply trying to create a window as a "listbox" and add elements to it.  My end goal will be a listbox similar to the on here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

[image: List Box Example]

I start by create a window with a listbox like so:

```
hDlg = CreateWindowExA(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        "ListBox",
        "The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

But from what I understand, `hDlg` now points to the entire window and not the listbox.

Ideally I want to be able to add items to the listbox similar to this:

```
int pos = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, 
                    (LPARAM) "Test Item1");
```

However I cannot get the handle of the list in the same way as the tutorial because they use this line:

```
HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LISTBOX_EXAMPLE);
```

but `IDC_LISTBOX_EXAMPLE` throws a compilation error because it isn't included anywhere.  And for the life of me, I cannot google a correct result for the second parameter `int nIDDlgItem`.

Can someone please explain to me how I can find the value `GetDlgItem()` or otherwise find a handle to my listbox from `CreateWindowExA()`?

Comment: The screenshot was not generated from that code, that list box is a WS_CHILD.

Comment: That is part of my confusion then... no where do they mention a WS_CHILD in the "How To create a Sample List Box"...

Comment: "Prerequisites: Windows User Interface Programming."  You are supposed to know this before tackling this example, so it doesn't show a CreateWindowEx() call.  It was actually a DialogBox() call.  Petzold explains this well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the predefined `ListBox` window class to create a top-level window.

```
hDlg = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "ListBox", ...
```

This is creating a listbox control. The second parameter to `CreateWindowEx` specifies the *window class* - this tells the system what type of window you want to create. Since you're passing `"ListBox"` for that value, it will be creating an instance of the `ListBox` class.

The trouble is that you're creating that window to be a top-level window. `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` is a window style used for top-level windows (i.e. the one titled "List Box Example" in the above screenshot). Child windows, such as the listbox control, need to have the `WS_CHILD` style set.

What you really need to do is use `RegisterClass` to register your own window class for the top-level window. You would use this class name when calling `CreateWindowEx` to create the main window, and **then** create the various controls as children of that window.

Comment: I understand registering a class and creating the window with that.  But how would I then create the child controls within that window?

Comment: Each control needs to be created individually, by passing the appropriate class name to `CreateWindowEx` and making sure the `WS_CHILD` style is set. Or use a dialog and the system does it all for you.

Comment: By the way, this is pretty basic Windows 101 stuff, you might want to try a book to get you started - the Petzold one is usually the gold standard for beginners.

Comment: Thanks.  My boss tasked me with creating a small GUI using the WINAPI which I am very unfamiliar with (linux background).  So I am trying to follow the MSDN articles but they seem to assume a bit more than I know.